# How to filter one array into multiple arrays depending on a specific value inside of the array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I am trying to filter an array of places into multiple arrays depending on the city, state (which I have labeled as address) of the place. I want all of the place objects with the same address to be grouped into one array so I can use that address as a header for each section in my tableView. I just don't know how to do it. I am not sure how to show any code for this but I have tried
`filteredPlaces.append(places.filter({ $0.address }))`
That didn't work at all.

I tried to loop through the `places` array, but I wasn't sure what code I needed in order to identify if any of the objects had the same address.

My current `filteredPlaces` array looks like this:
`var filteredPlaces = [[Place]()]` and my current array that is holding all of the places, looks like this: `var places = [Place]()`

How can I create separate arrays based on the address of each place in one array?

Here is my place object class

```
class Place {
    
    var name: String
    var street: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var zip: String
    var drinks: [Drink]
    
    var address: String {
        return "\(city), \(state)"
    }
    
    init(name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String, drinks: [Drink]) {
        self.name = name.uppercased()
        self.street = street.uppercased()
        self.city = city.uppercased()
        self.state = state.uppercased()
        self.drinks = drinks
        self.zip = zip
        
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String, drinks: [Drink]?) {
        if drinks != nil {
            self.init(name: name, street: street, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, drinks: drinks)
        } else {
            self.init(name: name, street: street, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, drinks: [Drink]())
        }
    }
    
}
```

I haven't created the declaration yet because that will be done when a user enters the places on a new viewController.

Comment: I think you’re looking for [`Dictionary.init(group:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init). Naturally, the result will be a dictionary (mapping an address key to an array value of all the places in that address). You can then flatten that back into an array if you wish.

Comment: Show your place object declaration

Comment: @LeoDabus I added my place object declaration

Comment: As per @Alexander, you can simply do this: `filteredPlaces = Array(Dictionary(grouping: places){$0.address}.values)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this, to obtain an dictionary of `adresses` with `Places`.

EDIT-1: using your `Place` class.

```
// example Places, 2 in Tokyo, and 3 in Sydney
        var places = [
            Place(name: "place-1", street: "street-1", city: "Tokyo", state: "Kanto", zip: "123", drinks: []),
            Place(name: "place-2", street: "street-2", city: "Tokyo", state: "Kanto", zip: "123", drinks: []),
            Place(name: "place-1", street: "street-1", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: []),
            Place(name: "place-2", street: "street-2", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: []),
            Place(name: "place-3", street: "street-3", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: [])]

// just for info 
let adrss = Set(places.map{$0.address})
print("\n---> unique adresses: \(adrss) \n")

// returns a dictionary where the key is the address and the value are the Places
let allPlaces: [String:[Place]] = Set(places.map{$0.address}).reduce(into: [:]) { dict, adrs in
    dict[adrs] = places.filter{$0.address == adrs}
}

 // an array of all places in Sydney
 print("\n---> all Places in Sydney: \(allPlaces["SYDNEY, NSW"]) \n")
 // an array of all places in Tokyo
 print("\n---> all Places in Tokyo: \(allPlaces["TOKYO, KANTO"]) \n")
```

The term `Set(places.map{$0.address})` gives you all unique addresses.
the `.reduce(into: [:])`, accumulates the `Places` for each address.
The result is a dictionary, with the key=the address and the value=the array of `Place`

Example usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var allPlaces: [String:[Place]] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(allPlaces.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
            Section(header: Text(key)) {
                ForEach(allPlaces[key] ?? []) { place in
                    Text(place.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        .onAppear {
            // example Places, 2 in Tokyo, and 3 in Sydney
            var places = [
                Place(name: "place-1", street: "street-1", city: "Tokyo", state: "Kanto", zip: "123", drinks: []),
                Place(name: "place-2", street: "street-2", city: "Tokyo", state: "Kanto", zip: "123", drinks: []),
                Place(name: "place-1", street: "street-1", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: []),
                Place(name: "place-2", street: "street-2", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: []),
                Place(name: "place-3", street: "street-3", city: "Sydney", state: "NSW", zip: "123", drinks: [])]
            
            // returns a dictionary where the key is the address and the value are the Places
            allPlaces = Set(places.map{$0.address}).reduce(into: [:]) { dict, adrs in
                dict[adrs] = places.filter{$0.address == adrs}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying so hard to understand this but I think I am just going to try this in my code and give it a shot. I understand things better when I do them. Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'll post what happens

Comment: updated my answer using your `Place` class, which probably should be a `struct`. Included an example usage in SwiftUI.

Comment: did my code not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`

The example is like

```
///     let students = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Efua", "Kweku", "Akosua"]
///     let studentsByLetter = Dictionary(grouping: students, by: { $0.first! })
///     // ["E": ["Efua"], "K": ["Kofi", "Kweku"], "A": ["Abena", "Akosua"]]
```

In your case you need something hashable for the key of the dictionary, so a hashable pair of place and street names:

```
  struct PlaceNameStreet: Hashable {
     let name: String
     let street: String
  }


  let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: places) { place in
     PlaceNameStreet(name: place.name, street: place.street)
  }
```